# unpacking tuples based on if statements

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I'm creating a nested dictionary with values from a tuple that is based on if statement. The variables in the code(estabilidad_atm, Q_puntos_muestreo and puntos de muestreo) are defined in the global scope. When I run the function I got and error saying: name a is not defined. I'm not sure why it isn't working... I've thought of applying namedtuple but I'm not sure which is the best way to proceed. Thanks!

```
variables_coeficientes_por_punto = {}

for punto in puntos_de_muestreo:
    x = punto[0]
    if estabilidad_atm == 'A' and x <= 1:
        a,c,d,f = (213,440.8,1.941,9.27)
    elif estabilidad_atm == 'A' and x > 1:
        a,c,d,f = (213,459.7,2.094,-9.6)
    elif estabilidad_atm == 'B' and x <= 1:
        a,c,d,f = (156,106.6,1.149,3.3)
    elif estabilidad_atm == 'B' and x > 1:
        a,c,d,f = (156,108.2,1.098,2)
    elif estabilidad_atm == 'C' and x <= 1:
        a,c,d,f = (104,61,0.911,0)
    elif estabilidad_atm == 'C' and x > 1:
        a,c,d,f = (104,61,0.911,0)
    elif estabilidad_atm == 'D' and x <= 1:
        a,c,d,f = (68,33.2,0.725,-1.7)
    elif estabilidad_atm == 'D' and x > 1:
        a,c,d,f = (68,44.5,0.516,-13)
    elif estabilidad_atm == 'E' and x <= 1:
        a,c,d,f = (50.5,22.8,0.678,-1.3)
    elif estabilidad_atm == 'E' and x > 1:
        a,c,d,f = (50.5,55.4,0.305,-34)
    elif estabilidad_atm == 'F' and x <= 1:
        a,c,d,f = (34,14.35,0.740,-0.35)
    elif estabilidad_atm == 'F' and x > 1:
        a,c,d,f = (34,62.6,0.180,-48.6)
    for i in range(Q_puntos_muestreo):
        variables_coeficientes_por_punto['punto '+ str(i+1)] = {}
        variables_coeficientes_por_punto['punto ' + str(i+1)]['a'] = a
        variables_coeficientes_por_punto['punto ' + str(i+1)]['c'] = c
        variables_coeficientes_por_punto['punto ' + str(i+1)]['d'] = d
        variables_coeficientes_por_punto['punto ' + str(i+1)]['f'] = f
```

Comment: If none of your conditions evaluate to `True` then `a` will not be defined.

Comment: You should add an `else:` after the chain of `elif`s, to either set default values for `a,c,d,f`, or raise a specific error.

Comment: This code is okay *(except absence of `else` block which have been mentioned in previous comments)*, there's no *switch* in python, so bunch of conditions is one of appropriate alternatives.

Comment: Unrelated. Instead of 4 separate assignments, you can just assign `{'a': a, 'c': c, 'd': d, 'f': f}`

Comment: You might also want to nest your conditions: `if estabilidad_atm == 'A': if x <= 1: ... else: ...`

Comment: I added the else, but it still doesn't work, I'm not really sure how to evaluate this condition to True, I'll be grateful if you help me figure it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many large `if` statements like this can be replaced with a `dict`. For example,

```
tuples = {
  'A': lambda x: (213,440.8,1.941,9.27) if x < 1 else (213,459.7,2.094,-9.6),
  'B': lambda x: (156,106.6,1.149,3.3) if x <= 1 else (156,108.2,1.098,2),
  ...
}

variables_coeficientes_por_punto = {}

for punto in puntos_de_muestreo:
    x = punto[0]
    try:
        a, c, d, f = tuples[estabilidad_atm](x)
    except KeyError:
        raise

    for i in range(1, Q_puntos_muestreo + 1):
        variables_coeficientes_por_punto['punto '+ str(i)] = dict(a=a, c=c, d=d, f=f)
```

This will raise a `KeyError` if `estabilidad_atm` is not a valid key, at which point you can optionally catch and do something sensible, rather than simply let your program exit.

Comment: Not sure if it will be better.

Comment: @OlvinRoght It's a standard practice and something that is actually expected wherever there's a place with a woul-be large ifelse ladder.

Comment: @BłażejMichalik, it's [**one of possible approaches**](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-isn-t-there-a-switch-or-case-statement-in-python), but I'm not sure is it most efficient.

Comment: @OlvinRoght pretty sure we're not really looking for efficiency here. Author made a mistake due to poor readability of the code. If you want efficiency, you might even look into doing it branchlessly in a C extension, but that sure as hell won't help readability.

Comment: @BłażejMichalik, ofc not, but imho `if .. elif .. else` is much more explicit.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Is it really? You can't see which path in the code the execution took, you don't see the resulting scope, and therefore you can't infer at a glance, which names are available after branching. You're explicit in the sense that `if...elif...else` is visible. But what is not explicit is the result, which is the raison d'être of this code.

Comment: @BłażejMichalik, that's why they added to docs next: *but there is no consensus (yet) on whether and how to do range tests*. XD I don't agree with your arguments, but it will take a while..

Comment: The `if` statement is less efficient, because you may have to make up to `n` comparisons to find your match, while the `dict` requires only one hash operation to find a match immediately. (This only works if you can cast your comparison as a lookup, of course.)

Comment: @chepner won't function calls trump any benefit of having a hash table instead of `if..else` ladder? After all, you're calling an additional lambda there.

Comment: It's not entirely about performance. It's unlikely that *this* part of the code is where you need the exact tuples to stand out. That said, you can ditch the functions and use tuples as the keys: `tuples = {('A', True): (...), ('A', False): (...), ..}`. Then `a, c, d, f = tuples[estabilidad_atm, (x<=1)]`.

Comment: @carlosdamann you should be thanking [at]chepner. I'm just commenting over *his* code.

Comment: @chepner yes, but you implied that hash mapped lambdas are more efficient than the `if...elif..else` ladder, which I'm quite sure is not true. It's more readable though - that's where the value of this solution lies.

Comment: Only a single function would be executed, regardless of how many functions there are to choose from. It's the ability to pick the right one with one hash operation and one comparison, rather than O(n) comparisons, that provides the improvement over the `if` statement.